# R: how to install from internet repos the dependencies of a package we install from local folder

Tags: r, install.packages

I have developped a R package and added some dependant CRAN package in the description file.
I then install it using install.packages

Is there a way to ensure that its dependencies are fetched at this moment from internet?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DESCRIPTION` file you  should add the lines:

```
Depends:
   package1 (>= 1.0.1),
   package2
```

The `(>= 1.0.1)` is for specifying minimal version.

More infos here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: I have done that but `install.packages` on this package doesn't go to CRAN to install package1 and package2. They are just missing and install.packages doesn't care. Is it because I install my package from a local file?

Comment: No, you should be able to install from local and install from CRAN your dependencies. Can you install usually from CRAN?

Comment: Could you provide more details on your package architechure, on DESCRIPTIOn files? Also, does it through an error a warning?